# AFNetworking GET request - unable convert responseObject to NSDictionary

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking-2

I have tried several option setting `responseSerializer` to `JSON` but i am unable to convert responseObject to `NSDictionary`. The problem is response i am getting is `NSData`

```
    NSString *baseURLString = @"Your URL?";
    NSString *str = @"adult=false&gender=male";

    NSString *url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",baseURLString,str];

    AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
    manager.responseSerializer = [AFHTTPResponseSerializer serializer];
    [manager GET:url parameters:nil success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id  responseObject) {
        // do whatever you'd like here; for example, if you want to convert
        // it to a string and log it, you might do something like:

        NSLog(@"responseObject %@",responseObject);

        NSString *jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseObject encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        NSLog(@"%@", jsonString);


    NSError* error;
    NSDictionary* json = [NSJSONSerialization
                          JSONObjectWithData:responseObject
                          options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers
                          error:&error];
    NSLog(@"json %@",json);

    if (error) {
        NSLog(@"%@",[error description]);
    }



    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
}];
```

This `NSLog(@"%@",[error description]);` gives error as follows:

```
Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "The operation couldn’t be completed. 
(Cocoa error 3840.)" (Garbage at end.) 
UserInfo=0xa7c5440 {NSDebugDescription=Garbage at end.}
```

Comment: But what format is the response object you're are retreiving from the request?

Comment: @MrBr - Its NSData i am able to convert it to string - jsonString

Comment: It might not be a valid JSON then, can you pars json string using `NSJSONSerialization`?

Comment: @YasKuraishi - Its not valid JSON, i have updated my question with NSJSONSerialization

Comment: Run Url in your browser http://www.broakenmedia.co.uk/kikfriends/scripts/json/read_from_db_json.php?adult=false&gender=male

Comment: At last you have seen this message .. This page was created in 0.010303020477295 seconds

Comment: That's is responsible for your error

Comment: Remove that message from your service response

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your JSON is coming back with garbage at the end.

[image]
You should fix your webservice to not embed timestamp and language at the end of your JSON. If you can not change your webservice, then use following to remove trailing garbage from your json before parsing it with `NSJSONSerialization` again.

```
NSRange range = [jsonString rangeOfString:@"}" options:NSBackwardsSearch];
jsonString = [jsonString substringToIndex:range.location + 1];
```

Then parse this cleaned up `jsonString` to `NSDictionary`:

```
NSData *newJSONData = [jsonString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSDictionary* json = [NSJSONSerialization
                          JSONObjectWithData:newJSONData
                          options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers
                          error:&error];
    NSLog(@"json %@",json);
```

It should work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Your data is not a valid JSON you can check in this [JSON Formatter](http://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/) provide the url or copy paste the JSON data and hit process you will see that its not a valid JSON.

The reason it not valid is it contains `This page was created in 0.0048439502716064 seconds` this message at the end of its response. If have control in the server side than try to stop sending this line in the end or try to remove this line and the convert it to NSDictionary. Hope this helps .. :)